# Error in sign up passport-local sign up routine

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm building an app in Node, using Passport and local signup and sign in strategies. I just keep running into an issue. All the required modules etc. are there. The following sign in routine works fine:

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqTodone : true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User not found.'));

        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Wrong password.'));

        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

However, the following sign up routine does not:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqTodone : true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    console.log("signing up")
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' : email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } else if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'That email address is already registered.'));
        } else {
            var newUser = new User();
        }

        // save the user
        newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error saving new user profile: " + err);
            } else {
                return done(null, newUser, req.flash('message', 'User account created'));
            }
        });
    });
}))
```

Both routines are called within routes.js:

```
// POST :   SIGNUP
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/error',
    failureFlash: true
}));

// POST :   SIGNIN
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Any ideas where it might go wrong? As is, posting to /signup continuously results in a failureRedirect. My head is getting kinda sore from banging on the screen...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Hi Myonara, I don't get an error message-- my log just shows 'GET /' which is because of failureRedirect; I've tried console logging within the routine, but it doesn't seem to respond to that. It's kinda odd; it is looking for the local-signup strategy but then within that strategy doesn't respond to console logging. Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Do you get the `console.log("signing up")` message? by the way a ; is missing there. If you getting this console, add additional console.logs to debug...

Comment: Hi Myonara, thanks for your reply! And apologies for my late reply; none of my console.logs show up-- it does call the routine passport.use('local-signup') but then doesn't seem to do anything within that block of code...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change is:

```
if (!user.validPassword(password))
```

To

```
if (user.validPassword(password) === false)
```

I know, if (!user.validPassword(password)) is in examples on Passport.js official docs, but it is wrong.

I have just lost 2 hours of my life, figuring this out.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code it will helps you to fix your problem

> passport-authentication.js

```
var express=require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');//user is schema

var Verify = require('./verify');//verify is a file where the user is verified 


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser,function(req, res, next) {
User.find({},function(err,user){
if(err) throw err;
res.json(user);
});
 });

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username,Email:req.body.Email}),
        req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
                if(req.body.firstname) {
            user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
        }
        if(req.body.lastname) {
            user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
        }
                user.save(function(err,user) {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
            });
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Bye!'
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

> verify.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../config.js');

exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};

exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

hope this helps for you...

Comment: Hi Syed, thanks for the suggestion; although I'm certain I could just copy/paste much of this, it doesn't help me understand where the error is in my code-- as far as I can see it should work just fine, but apparently it doesn't...

Comment: @Martin Why don't you use the complete code which I provided you .In my code I too use passport authentication.What else you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I'm trying to understand the mechanics of the routines and particularly since the structuring and organization of the rest of my code and files is very different, I'd be more useful for me to actually know the proper syntax and how to properly implement and call the correct functions. Thanks again though! If you have any suggestions as to why my original code didn't work, I'd be very interested in hearing them :)

Comment: So You want to understand the syntaxes and each and everything. For that please signup for coursera website there you can search  as Server-Side Development with nodejs,Express and MongoDB . You can watch all the videos explained by professor. You will get it so clear .

Comment: Hi Syed, I think you're missing the point. I have taken a course in Node.js and Mongo, but not strictly on middleware such as Passport. Rather than copy/pasting someone else's code I'm more interested in understanding why my code doesn't work, particularly because I have taken a course, followed everything to the letter, and it still doesn't seem to work. I would like to understand my error to become a better coder.